# Main processing flow programmatic approach when using Spring Integration with Project Reactor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

I want to define a flow that consumes kafka with Reactor Kafka and writes to MongoDB, and only on success writes the IDs to Kafka. I'm using the Project Reactor with Spring Integration JavaDSL, and I'd wish to have a `FlowBuilder` class that defines my pipeline at a high level. I currently have the following direction:

```java
public IntegrationFlow buildFlow() {
   return IntegrationFlows.from(reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate)
      .publishSubscribeChannel(c -> c
                        .subscribe(sf -> sf
                                .handle(MongoDb.reactiveOutboundChannelAdapter())) 
      .handle(writeToKafka)
      .get();
}
```

I've seen in the [docs that there is a support for a different approach, that also works with Project Reactor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/gateway.html#reactor-mono). This approach doesn't include the use of `IntegrationFlows`. This looks like this:

```java
@MessagingGateway
public static interface TestGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "promiseChannel")
    Mono<Integer> multiply(Integer value);

    }

        ...

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "promiseChannel")
    public Integer multiply(Integer value) {
            return value * 2;
    }

        ...

    Flux.just("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .flatMap(this.testGateway::multiply)
            .collectList()
            .subscribe(integers -> ...);
```

I'd like to know what is more of a recommended way of processing when working with these two libraries. I wonder how can I use the Reactive MongoDB adapter in the second example. I'm not sure if the second approach is even possible without an `IntegrationFlows` wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@MessagingGateway` was designed for high-level end-user API, to hide messaging underneath as much as possible. So, the target service is free from any messaging abstraction when you develop its logic.

It is possible to use such an interface adapter from the `IntegrationFlow` and you should treat it as regular service activator therefore it would look like this:

```
.handle("testGateway", "multiply", e -> e.async(true))
```

The `async(true)` to make this service activator to subscribe to the returned `Mono`. You may omit this then you are on your own to subscriber to it downstream since exactly this `Mono` is going to be a `payload` for the next message in the flow.

If you want to have something opposite: call an `IntegrationFlow` from the `Flux`, like that `flatMap()`, then consider to use a `toReactivePublisher()` operator from the flow definition to return a `Publisher<?>` and declare it as a bean. In this case it is better to not use that `MongoDb.reactiveOutboundChannelAdapter()`, but just `ReactiveMongoDbStoringMessageHandler` to let its returned `Mono` to be propagated to that `Publisher`.

On the other hand if you want to have that `@MessagingGateway` with the `Mono` return, but still call from it a `ReactiveMongoDbStoringMessageHandler`, then declare it as a bean and mark it with that `@ServiceActivator`.

We also have an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to catch errors (or success) on the particular endpoint and handle them respectively: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#expression-advice

I think what you are looking for is like this:

```
public IntegrationFlow buildFlow() {
   return IntegrationFlows.from(reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate)
      .handle(reactiveMongoDbStoringMessageHandler, "handleMessage")
      .handle(writeToKafka)
      .get();
}
```

Pay attention to the `.handle(reactiveMongoDbStoringMessageHandler)` - it is not about a `MongoDb.reactiveOutboundChannelAdapter()`. Because this one wraps a `ReactiveMessageHandler` into a `ReactiveMessageHandlerAdapter` for automatic subscription. What you need is look more like you'd like to have that `Mono<Void>` returned to your own control, so you can use it as an input into your `writeToKafka` service and subscribe there yourself and handle success or error as you explained. The point is that with Reactive Stream we cannot provide an imperative error handling. The approach is the same like with any async API usage. So, we send errors to the `errorChannel` for Reactive Streams, too.

We probably can improve that `MongoDb.reactiveOutboundChannelAdapter()` with something like `returnMono(true/false)` to let the use-case like your to be available out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I understand correctly, II currently don't have a reason to use an adapter that implements `ReactiveMessageHandler` if I want to control the reactive subscription myself. So yes if there would be a `returnMono` option that would improve that.

Comment: For a case, I'd like to move the `reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate` into a different class. The recommended way is the implement a `ReactorKafkaInboundChannelAdapter`?

Comment: Yes. That's possible. See `MongoDbChangeStreamMessageProducer` as a sample how to implement a message-driven channel adapter for reactive source.

Comment: Can you explain what makes it a Channel Adapter? I thought after reading the docs that a channel adapter must implement `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` or be annotated by `@InboundChannelAdapter`. I only see that `MongoDbChangeStreamMessageProducer` implements `MessageProducerSupport ` so I'm pretty confused by the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/channel-adapter.html#channel-adapter) from this.

Comment: Right. The channel adapter is a common abstraction. The types are: source polling, outbound, gateway and message-driven. I consider that `ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate` as the last one, just because it provides for us a `Flux` to subscribe. We don't need the polling channel adapter for this use-case since there is better approach for it - message-driven. We need polling for those protocol which does not provide a listener hook. So, we poll it periodically. See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#messaging-endpoints-chapter

Comment: I see. So for creating a message-driven inbound channel adapter I should basically implement `MessageProducerSupport`?

Comment: Correct. And that's why I pointed out to that `MongoDbChangeStreamMessageProducer` which has similar reactive feature. So, you can fully borrow whatever it does for preparing the `Flux` and how it calls `subscribeToPublisher(changeStreamFlux);` in the end. Same you do for that `ReactiveKafkaMessageProducer`. When you are satisfied with the solution, feel free contribute it back to Spring Integration: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues !

Comment: Great I’ll try. I also wonder what is the correct way of using it in an application. If I have such a `FlowBuilder` class and I want to customize the parameters of `ReactiveKafkaMessageProducer` and move it to a separate class, should the wrapping class also be a channel adapter?

Comment: I feel that I don’t understand into what kind of class / type of function shall I move a too long and complex channel adapter usage (because of logging, configurations and more)